# Javascript loop value appears as undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, undefined

I am having an issue trying to create a loop that changes an image using an if statement in Java-script. I have this set up with four buttons, each button assigned a distinct color. When the button is clicked, the loop is supposed to find the index of the button using buttons[i] to show what was the color chosen using if else statements by choosing the correct index. However, when I click on the button, only the "else" statement is executed and when I went to inspect more, the value of buttons[i] appears to be undefined. What can I do to make sure it is assigned the correct index, and not the value of undefined?

Here is my java-script code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
   var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
   for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].onclick = function () {
         var switcher = buttons[i];
         if (switcher == 0 ) {
            const t = "test.json"
            fetch(t)
               .then(function (response) {
                  return response.json();
               })
               .then(function (jsonObject) {
                  const color = jsonObject['color'];
                  for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                     let colorTitle = document.createElement('section');
                     let colorName = document.createElement('h2');
                     colorName.textContent = color[0].name;
                     colorTitle.appendChild(colorName);
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').appendChild(colorTitle);
                     var img = document.createElement("img");
                     img.src = color[0].image;
                     var oldImg = document.getElementById('bigpic');
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').replaceChild(img, oldImg);

                  };
               });
         }
         else if (switcher == 1) {
            const t = "test.json"
            fetch(t)
               .then(function (response) {
                  return response.json();
               })
               .then(function (jsonObject) {
                  const color = jsonObject['color'];
                  for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                     let colorTitle = document.createElement('section');
                     let colorName = document.createElement('h2');
                     colorName.textContent = color[1].name;
                     colorTitle.appendChild(colorName);
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').appendChild(colorTitle);
                     var img = document.createElement("img");
                     img.src = color[1].image;
                     var oldImg = document.getElementById('bigpic');
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').replaceChild(img, oldImg);

                  };
               });
         }
         else {
            const t = "test.json"
            fetch(t)
               .then(function (response) {
                  return response.json();
               })
               .then(function (jsonObject) {
                  const color = jsonObject['color'];
                  for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                     let colorTitle = document.createElement('section');
                     let colorName = document.createElement('h2');
                     colorName.textContent = color[2].name;
                     colorTitle.appendChild(colorName);
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').appendChild(colorTitle);
                     var img = document.createElement("img");
                     img.src = color[2].image;
                     var oldImg = document.getElementById('bigpic');
                     document.querySelector('div.api-wrapper').replaceChild(img, oldImg);
                     console.log(switcher);

                  };
               });
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: `i` is not scoped down to the event handler that uses it.  As such `i` will be beyond the bounds of the `buttons` array when any of them are clicked.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I ended up using let instead of var to fix the scope of it.